# How to create a transaction log on WinSCP on SSIS package

Tags: ssis, winscp, dtexec

I have SSIS package, which uses winscp to execute some commands in a text file to upload files to a FTP site. I use DTExec.exe to execute this SSIS package. Right now, I need to show winscp FTP log including display file name uploaded on FTP site. Does someone know how to capture the log? I use '>' and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP can generate [its own log](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging) using [`/log` command-line switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) (or `/xmllog`):

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt /log=winscp.log
```

---

If you want to just capture WinSCP console output:

- Make sure you are using [`winscp.com`, not `winscp.exe`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables).
- Run `winscp.com` via `cmd.exe`, as that is what understands the `>`.

```
cmd.exe /C winscp.com /script=script.txt > winscp.log
```

---

*In both cases, you will typically need to use full paths to all files (`winscp.com`, `script.txt`, `winscp.log`).*

Comment: Thank you. But how to capture the log on SSIS and DTExec.exe

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"?

Comment: Display the command and file name after the file is uploaded to FTP site.